# Functional values

Tags: functions

My problem is:

Given that $(-1,7)$ is on the graph of $f(x)$, find the corresponding point for the function $f(x+3)$

I think I know the answer, $(-1, 14)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Let's check: If $(-1,14)$ were on the graph of $f(x+3)$, then what that would mean is that $f(-1 + 3) = 14$, that is $f(2) = 14$.  But we don't know anything about $f(2)$, so no, we don't know this for sure.

Comment: How did you get (-1,14)?

Comment: I took the -1 and added it with the 3 and then multiplied by 7 to get 14. I guess I had the wrong idea. So how would I go about solving this?

Comment: If a point is on the graph of $f(x) $ then it satisfies $(x, f(x))$ now instead of $x$ try plugging in $x+3$ and adjusting so you get something you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provide only one point from the graph of $f$: $(x,y=f(x)) = (-1, 7)$.

So the only point of $g(x) = f(x+3)$ we can say something about is if $x+3 = -1$ or $x = -4$.

Of course the value is $g(-4) = f(-4 + 3) = f(-1) = 7$ and the point thus $(-4, 7)$.

Answer (score 0):

hint:

Let $g(x)=f(x+3)$.

We know that $f(-1)=7$.

Can you compute $g(-4)$ for us?